Using ROAPI to connect database but return curl error 52
I'm trying to use the prebuilt roapi docker container to connect to the testing postgres database.
However, it returns the curl error 52: Empty reply from sever.
Despite this , I can use DBeaver client tool to connect to the testing database and the connection works fine.
I am a beginner so the question might be silly and any help will be appreciated !
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/api/table -H 'Content-Type : application/json'
-d '[{
"tableName":"testabc",
"uri":"postgresql://postgres:postgres@myip/roapitest"
}
]'

ROAPI Documentation：https://roapi.github.io/docs/quickstart.html
ps. I checked the following information and it works fine :

The RoAPI Docker container is running and accessible at localhost:8083.
The PostgreSQL database credentials and URL are correct.


Can you include either the docker file or the command you used to stand up the docker container?
